# OpenGL showing stripes when using sampler2D

Tags: c++, opengl

I encountered a strange issue when trying to write an OpenGL application in C++. After reducing the code I found out that the issue is something with texture sampling. On top of the texture there are strange stripes:
[image: Stripes error]

What is supposed to be drawn is a rectangle with this texture:
[image]

Strangely, when I resize the window, the thickness of the stripes changes too:
[image]

I don't think that there is anything wrong with the shaders, but here they are:

```
//-----------------Vertex-----------------
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos_;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color_;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 uv_;

out vec2 uv;

void main()
{
    uv = uv_;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos_, 1.0);
}
```

```
//-----------------Fragment---------------
#version 330 core

out vec4 frag_color;

in vec2 uv;

uniform sampler2D diffuse_;

void main()
{
    frag_color = texture(diffuse_, uv);
}
```

I also think that its probably not the cause of texture loading issue, but regardless here it is:

```
GLuint load_texture(const std::string& source)
{
    GLuint texture = 0;

    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(source.c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data != nullptr)
    {
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    return texture;
}
```

In addition, if it can help, here I provide the code for assigning the vertex attributes:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(0 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

And setting the texture uniform:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, diffuse);

glUseProgram(shader);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "diffuse_"), 0);
```

Sorry, if that's a lot of code, but I don't know where the issue is. Have anyone of you seen something like this before and knows how to fix this?

Comment: Just a guess, Inside stbi_load(), try unsing STBI_rgb_alpha instead of that last 0.

Comment: @ShockCoding Unfortunately, that didn't help, but thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: @YanB. Does stbimage agree that `nrChannels==3`? Because that is what you promised OpenGL.

Comment: @Botje, That was the issue. Thanks so much! Its strange that `nrChannels` is 4. After all the texture doesn't have any transparency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Botje the problem was solved. The amount of channels given to OpenGL with `glTexImage2D` was not equal to `nrChannels`. I was able to solve that with a simple `switch` inside `load_texture`. Here is the updated version:

```
GLuint load_texture(const std::string& source)
{
    GLuint texture = 0;

    int width, height, nrChannels;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(source.c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data != nullptr)
    {
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        GLenum format;
        switch (nrChannels)
        {
        case 1:
            format = GL_LUMINANCE;
            break;
        case 2:
            format = GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA;
            break;
        case 3:
            format = GL_RGB;
            break;
        case 4:
            format = GL_RGBA;
            break;
        }

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    return texture;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could have passed 3 for the last argument of `stbi_load`, that forces the number of components to 3, regardless of what the file contains.

Comment: @Botje Thanks again, now I know what that parameter is for. But I will leave it like this so it will work with any kind of texture.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when loading a jpg image.Setting GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT fixed it. https://github.com/nothings/stb/issues/695

```
    if (channels == 3) {
        //HERE WAS THE MISTAKE
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); 
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

    }
```